# .each function does not run on last element

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have 2 `div` with the `.image__content` class and within that, I have some images with unique ids. I need to hide all the images and only show 1 image from each `.image__content`, at the moment you can see all the images.

The code below is meant to get each `.image__content` which it does and then run the code individually for each `.image__content`, getting the current image id from a select option and finding the image with the same id and displaying that image and hiding the rest.

However, at the moment it only works for the last `.image__content`, so it does exactly what I want it to do but only for the 2nd `.image__content` and the first `div` it hides all the images and doesn't even show one.

So how would I be able to run the function and for it to be workable for both .image__content?

```
<div class="image__content">
  <div class="images">
    <img class="image image-1">
    <img class="image image-2">
    <img class="image image-3">
  </div>

<form>
  <select class="image__select">
    <option value="1">Image 1</option>
    <option value="2">Image 2</option>
    <option value="3">Image 3</option>
  </select>
</form>
</div>

<div class="image__content">
  <div class="images">
    <img class="image image-4">
    <img class="image image-5">
    <img class="image image-6">
  </div>

<form>
  <select class="image_select">
    <option value="4">Image 4</option>
    <option value="5">Image 5</option>
    <option value="6">Image 6</option>
  </select>
</form>
</div>
```

```
  $('.image__content').each(function() {

      var s = $('form').find('.image_select').val();

      console.log(s);

      var imageId = '.image-'+ s;
      $(".image").hide();
      $(imageId).show();

  });
```

Comment: Why do you have only one form?? You should have two, no?

Comment: `$("image")` should be `$(".image")`

Comment: Your callback for `.each` is a function that just defines a variable `foo` that is a function. But nothing calls `foo`. So your callback has no effect.

Comment: Now that you've changed your code per comments, does it still not work?

Comment: No, it didn't but I have just seen an answer below so I will try that out

Comment: @Benjk PS: be aware that `image__select` !== `image_select`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Assign the same image ID to the option `value`
- Inside the  `.image__content`'s each, while you target inner elements, reference always to the parent Element using `$(***, this);`  meaning: *"descendant of THIS specific .image__content*
- Create a CSS class `.is-active` to handle the state of active images
- Use jQuery's `.trigger()` to init

```js
$('.image__content').each(function() {

  const $images = $('.image', this);         // Cache your selectors
  const $select = $('.image__select', this); // Reference using: this

  $select.on('change', function() {
    const $img = $images.filter(`#${this.value}`); // Get the one!
    $images.not($img).removeClass("is-active");    // Hide other images
    $img.addClass("is-active");                    // Show the one!
  }).trigger('change');

});
```

```css
.image__content .image {
  display: none;
}

.image__content .image.is-active {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="image__content">
  <div class="images">
    <img id="a_1" class="image" src="https://placehold.it/100x100/0bf?text=1">
    <img id="a_2" class="image" src="https://placehold.it/100x100/f0b?text=2">
    <img id="a_3" class="image" src="https://placehold.it/100x100/b0f?text=3">
  </div>

  <select class="image__select">
    <option value="a_1">Image 1</option>
    <option value="a_2">Image 2</option>
    <option value="a_3">Image 3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="image__content">
  <div class="images">
    <img id="b_1" class="image" src="https://placehold.it/100x100/fb0?text=4">
    <img id="b_2" class="image" src="https://placehold.it/100x100/bf0?text=5">
    <img id="b_3" class="image" src="https://placehold.it/100x100/0fb?text=6">
  </div>

  <select class="image__select">
    <option value="b_1">Image 4</option>
    <option value="b_2">Image 5</option>
    <option value="b_3">Image 6</option>
  </select>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: It would probably help the OP if you explained  **why** you did what you did (what's wrong with the OP's approach) and not just post code.

Comment: Yes *sometimes* that is true. It's not just a question of whether the OP will (eventually) understand your code, but they may not understand what's wrong with their approach. Yes, time is $, which makes me wonder why I spend any time at all on SO. ;)